# ZeroDivisionError - acts_as_votable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am using acts_as_votable for upvotes and downvotes. Now I am trying to show an 'approval rating', calculated by upvotes / total votes.

The problem is there are some resources in the database with 0 total votes, hence the ZeroDivisionError. How do I fix this?

In the view:

```
<td><%= "#{guide.upvotes.count/guide.votes.count}" %></td>
```

In the controller:

```
  def upvote
    @guide = Guide.find(params[:id])
    @guide.liked_by current_user
    redirect_to :back
  end

  def downvote
    @guide = Guide.find(params[:id])
    @guide.downvote_from current_user
    redirect_to :back
  end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can test for a non-zero denominator.  You can do this in your view:

```
<td><%= "#{guide.upvotes.count/guide.votes.count}" if guide.votes.count > 0 %></td>
```

Or, better, you can have a helper_method that does this for you:

```
def rating(guide)
  guide.votes.count > 0 ? (guide.upvotes.count / guide.votes.count) : 0
end
```

And call that in your view:

```
<td><%= rating(guide) %></td>
```

Or, even better, add it to your Guide model:

```
def rating
  votes.count > 0 ? (upvotes.count / votes.count) : 0
end
```

And in your view...

```
<td><%= guide.rating %></td>
```

Comment: Thanks! Do you, by any chance, know how to format the number as a percentage?

Comment: Sure, you can use the [`number_to_percentage`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/NumberHelper.html#method-i-number_to_percentage) helper, although this will require you to first multiply the rating by 100...